Celery Task auto-discovery from sub-folder of task modules
I have used Celery for a while now (not Django involved), but all of my tasks have always been defined in one main tasks.py file like this:
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker=["amqp://..."],
    backend="redis://..."
)
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@app.task(
    bind=True,
    max_retries=5,
    autoretry_for=(
        ...
    )
)
def my_task(self, ...):
    <task code here>

...

Over time the project has grown quite large and I am trying to breakout these tasks into various modules depending on the systems they interact with (databases, APIs, etc.). I want to load all of these module tasks using the app.autodiscover_tasks() function but keep running into ModuleNotFoundError.
Below is an example of my project structure and sample codes:
my_project/
|  app.py
|  celery_tasks/
|  |  moduleA/
|  |  |  __init__.py
|  |  |  tasks.py
|  |  moduleB/
|  |  |  __init.py
|  |  |  tasks.py

app.py now contains:
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker=["amqp://..."],
    backend="redis://..."
)
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
app.autodiscover_tasks(['.celery_tasks.moduleA', '.celery_tasks.moduleB'])

celery_tasks/moduleA/__init__.py:
from .tasks import *

celery_tasks/moduleA/tasks.py:
from celery import Task
from app import app

class ModuleA(Task):
    bind = True
    max_retries = 5
    autoretry_for = ( ... )

@app.task(base=ModuleA)
def my_task(self, ...):
    <task code here>

I have tried this multiple ways with different structures--  Like removing the celery_tasks/ parent folder and having each module live at the root of the project with app.py and referencing them like app.autodiscover_tasks(['moduleA', 'moduleB']), but it gives me the same errors about No module named 'moduleA'.
This seems to be just what the documentation describes, but it can be a bit terse at times and I'm sure I am missing something simple.
Can someone please point me in the right direction (without making me feel like a complete idiot)? =)
Environment

Python 3.12 (Alpine Linux container)
Celery 5.4.0

